# Two Lists Categories and SubCategories

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have following 2 lists

```
- `List<Category>`
- `List<SubCategory>`

        public class Category
        {
            public string CategoryId 
           {
               get;
               set;
           }

           public List<SubCategory> subCategories
           {
               get;
               set;
           }


    public string Name
{
get;
set;
}
        }


        public class SubCategory
        {
             public string SubCategoryId
             {
                 get;
                 set;
             }
            public string CategoryId 
            {
                 get;
                 set;
            }
            public string Name
            {
                 get;
                 set;
            }
         }
```

1. I want to find the matching categories (by CategoryId) in both Categories and SubCategories.
2. Add all the subcategories with a particular CategoryId to the subCategories array of Category with the same CategoryId of CategoriesList.

So far I have tried.

```
var categories = Categories.Select(c => c.Id);

            foreach(Guid categoryId in categories)
            {
                var subCategoriesByCategoryId = validatedSubCategories.Where(subCats => subCats.CategoryId == categoryId);
                List<SubCategory> subCategories = new List<SubCategory>();
                foreach(SubCategory subCategory in subCategoriesByCategoryId)
                {
                    subCategories.Add(subCategory);
                }

                if (subCategories.Count() > 0)
                {
var categoryById = Categories.FirstOrDefault(vC => vC.Id == categoryId);
if (categoryById != null) categoryById.SubCategories = subCategories;
                }
            }
```

How do I achieve this?

Sample Data

```
Category cat1= new Category {CategoryId=1};
Category cat2= new Category {CategoryId=2};
Category cat3= new Category {CategoryId=3};
Category cat4= new Category {CategoryId=4};

List<Category > Categories = new List<Category >()
Categories.Add(cat1);
Categories.Add(cat2);
Categories.Add(cat3);
Categories.Add(cat4);

SubCategory sc1 = new SubCategory {CategoryId=1);
SubCategory sc2 = new SubCategory{CategoryId=2};
SubCategory sc3 = new SubCategory{CategoryId=3};
SubCategory sc4 = new SubCategory{CategoryId=4};

List<SubCategory> SubCategories = new List<SubCategory >()
SubCategories.Add(sc1);
SubCategories.Add(sc1);
SubCategories.Add(sc3);
SubCategories.Add(sc4);
```

Expected outPut is

2 Subcategory items from Subcategories with CategoryId 1 should be added to the Category Item having CategoryId 1 in CategoryList

1 Subcategory item from Subcategories with CategoryId 3 should be added to the Category item having CategoryId 3 in CategoryList

1 Subcategory item from Subcategories with CategoryId 4 should be added to the Category item having CategoryId 4 in CategoryList

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code? Also can you share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (on .NETFiddle for example)?

Comment: would be good if you have a sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try on below statement:**

```
List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
List<SubCategory> subCategories = new List<SubCategory>();

var matchingCategories = from mt in categories
    join sub in subCategories
        on mt.CategoryId equals sub.CategoryId
    group sub by new { mt.CategoryId, mt.Name}
    into grp
    select new Category() {CategoryId = grp.Key.CategoryId , Name = grp.Key.Name, subCategories = grp.ToList()};

var result = matchingCategories.ToList();
```

Comment: I want to include Category Name also into the list.